# elasticsearch 6.5: reindex random sample of documents from remote 2.4 cluster results in illegal_argument_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to reindex a random sample of documents from a remote elasticsearch 2.4 cluster into a new elasticsearch 6.5 cluster. I'm trying to adapt this example (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/docs-reindex.html#_extracting_a_random_subset_of_an_index) to remote reindexing:

Example:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "size": 10,
  "source": {
    "index": "twitter",
    "query": {
      "function_score" : {
        "query" : { "match_all": {} },
        "random_score" : {}
      }
    },
    "sort": "_score"    
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "random_twitter"
  }
}
```

Adapted to remote reindex:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:9200/_reindex -d '
{
  "size": 100,
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://REMOTE_HOST:9200"
    },
    "index": "myindex",
    "query": {
      "function_score" : {
        "query" : { "match_all": {} },
        "random_score" : {}
      }
    },
    "sort": "_score"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "myindex"
  }
}'
```

This returns status code 400 and the following message:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unsupported sort [{\n  \"_score\" : {\n    \"order\" : \"desc\"\n  }\n}]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unsupported sort [{\n  \"_score\" : {\n    \"order\" : \"desc\"\n  }\n}]"},"status":400}
```

So sorting by _score does not seem to work. When I remove the _score sorting, it works fine - however, the sample is not really random then, as stated in the documentation.

Is this not possible when reindex from a remote, or am I doing something wrong? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to specify the sort like this:

```
"sort": {"_score": "desc" }
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, that doesn't help (same error).